# While creating new document in ravendb, collection name is missing in metadata, and the document is marked under @empty collection

Tags: graphql, ravendb, apollo-client, document-database, ravendb-studio

I am trying to create a new collection in ravendb using the apollo node client. Although the document is created and stored in ravendb, the "collection" value from metadata is missing. And as a result the document is stored under @empty collection. Wondering what is it that I am missing.

Comment: How do you create the document? can you provide some code ?
Try to create with document name all lower-case !

Comment: @Danielle Below is a snippet of how I store the document. I am using the apollo node client. 

```const sched: IScheduling = { appointment: { id: 'appointments/1-A', client: { id: 'clients/1-A', name: 'Entity', }, }, status: 'Pending', tier: 1, sendOn: new Date() }; await session.store<Scheduling>(sched); await session.saveChanges(); ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the solution. The issue was caused because I was trying to pass an on the fly Json object of an interface type, while it is required to pass an object of the class, implementing the interface. RavenDB uses the object's class name to set the id and to organize the documents under collections.

Answer (score 2):

1. If you are using **Object Literals** for the entities to be stored, then you need to set `findCollectionNameForObjectLiteral()` on the `DocumentStore`, before calling `initialize()`

```
const store = new DocumentStore(urls, database);
store.conventions.findCollectionNameForObjectLiteral = entity => entity["collection"];
// ...
store.initialize();
```

This must be done **before** the initialize() call on DocumentStore instance.
 
Otherwise, entities are created in the @empty collection.

See https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb-nodejs-client#using-object-literals-for-entities

2. If you are using **classes** for entities to be stored, then an instance of the class must be passed to `store()` 
   See: https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb-nodejs-client#using-classes-for-entities